# Click event not working after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a wp site which has an Ajax filter and I am using some javascript code to run with the filter, this code works fine when the page loads and it does not work once the Ajax filter is activated. Only the click event is not working.

```
function addStoreLinkListeners() {
  const store_url = document.querySelectorAll('.store-name-clickable .jet-listing-dynamic-link__link');
  store_url.forEach(url => { 
    const parentItem = url.closest('.grid-name-clickable .jet-listing-grid__item');
    if (parentItem) {
      console.log("Adding click listener to parent item:", parentItem);
      parentItem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.log("Parent item clicked");
        const clickedElement = event.target;
        if (!clickedElement.closest('.preview-buttons')) {
          event.preventDefault();
          window.open(url.getAttribute('href'), '_self');
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

// Call the function once on page load
addStoreLinkListeners();

// Call the function again after each AJAX request is complete
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log("AJAX request complete");
  addStoreLinkListeners();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't publish where you are adding the items to the DOM so maybe this answer will need to be adjusted.

But from what I see you are intercepting all AJAX requests, so when the request for data for the filtered data completes you reattach the 'click' event.

The problem is that the ajaxComplete event occurs before the elements are added to the DOM because JS will try to run your event listener that reattachs "addStoreLinkListeners" and the event listener that adds data to the DOM.

As a time graph to help you visualize:

```
Search filter Changed
|-> Create AJAX req.
     |-> AJAX req. Compl.
          |--> Your Event Listener (exec faster)
          |--> Evt to replace DOM elem (exec slower)
```

I suggest that if you have access to the code that replaces the HTML elements with the filtered data received from the server add the call to your function to the end of it.

If you don't have access to it, as a quick and dirty way, add a setTimeout to your event listener, does not need to have a lot of time to wait but should resolve the issue:

```js
// Call the function again after each AJAX request is complete
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log("AJAX request complete");
  setTimeout(function() {
    addStoreLinkListeners();
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: very detailed and well explained answer.+1